# What curve is described by $s = \langle 2t,9\sin t,9\cos t\rangle$?

Tags: calculus, geometry

What type of curve is described by the following?
$$s = \langle 2t,9\sin(t),9\cos(t)\rangle$$

**Attempt**

The $j$ and $k$ components of the curve describe a circle of radius $3$ in the $j-k$ plane and the $i$ component is linear. How can the type of curve be determined from this?

Comment: I think you'll find it's a helix lined up on the $x$ axis.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know this from experience or is there a nice way to figure that out?

Comment: Both. The $y$ and $z$ components describe a circle, by themselves. The $x$ coordinate is just going to march out steadily. If you imagine that in your mind, it comes out to a helix.

Comment: From experience it is quickly recognizable as a helix, but you can also figure it out by noting that the projection of the curve on the $yz$-plane is a circle of radius 9 centered at the origin and the $x$-component climbs out of the $yz$-plane at a constant rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be of help

[image]

Built using a simple python script

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num = 200)
x = 2 * t
y = 9 * np.sin(t)
z = 9 * np.cos(t)

ax.plot(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Great - thanks for this!